# Listview doesn't display on iPhone but displays on the simulator and other browsers

Tags: listview, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

My Application has a `Sencha Touch` `ListView` & i am loading some records from `http://localhost/MyProj/app/php/file.php` (It's a `JSON` ). It returns a JSON string. When i tested the app on the browser (`safari`,`chrome` and `firefox`) and also on the `iphone simulator` and it worked fine.

But, when i opened the application on Safari on the `iphone`, the `ListView` doesn't display. How can i solve this ?

The `URL` i types in the safari browser is the same as the `URL` i typed on Safari on the iphone device.

**eg:** `http://localhost/MyProj/app.html`

Note: THis is a Sencha touch application

**UPDATE**

I also tried adding a new Listview and hard coding some value, but still the hard coded values doesn't appear on the device, but works on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, the url is in `localhost`. Your phone can't access your system's localhost. So, it fails. Use IP Address. your iPhone can only get data from internet. Your server is just in your system. not on net. You should move your localhost server code to some web server to use it in real device.

Comment: I did use the ip address, which is `192.168.0.55`. Its the same blank listview that i get

Comment: Is that URL accessible to outside world? Check if you can hit the url outside your system's network. Probably, try to hit it from your iPhone's browser.

Comment: Well, i tried accessing the url 'http://192.168.0.55/MyProj/app/php/file.php' and i see a JSON string on the safari mobile browser. Note: I am also connected to the same wifi network.